# Start NestJS server even if TypeORM module can't connect to one of its databases

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I have multiple Databases with TypeORM in `app.module`.
One of them like this:

```js
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'mssql',
        host: configService.get('HOST'),
        port: 1434,
        username: configService.get('USERNAME'),
        database: 'testdatabase', 
        password: configService.get('PASSWORD'),
        name: 'myDatabase', 
        entities: [],
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
      name: 'myDatabase',
    }),
```

**Question**:
How can I run the server even if the Database can't be connected to? My controllers can handle the case when the database is down and can't give me any data, but right now the entire server won't start unless the connection is successful. I Want my server to be able to run even if the (remotely hosted) DB is offline - thus reducing the dependencies it needs to run.

Currentlyif the *host* is unavailable, nest will retry continuously or only 5 times if `retryAttempts: 5` is present. Then it will shut down

Answer (score 2):

`@nestjs/typeorm` doesn't offer this capability. If you need to be able to start the server regardless if the TypeORM connection is available, you'll need to create your own `TypeormModule` that continues even when the database is down